# Overriding class Magento 2.1

Tags: blocks, magento-2.1, overrides

I'm trying to inject \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager Object to be able to use truncate fucnction in list.phtml

```
     $this->_filter->truncate($string, ['length' => $length, 'etc' => '...'])
```

So I overwride \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct. Everything is connected properly. I Overwride this method

```
  public function getLoadedProductCollection(){
           var_dump('working');
 }
```

It's properly returning the string 'Working'. Now the problem comes when I use the __construct and try to inject Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager Class within the constructor. So i'm trying to do

```
    protected $_filterManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        $this->_filterManager = $filterManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
```

I clean cache, but the page fails to load giving this error.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:12622:"#0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    $this->filterManager = $filterManager;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}
```

Comment: Still having the same issue. The site keeps breaking whenever I try to use the __Construct

Comment: Delete var/generation/* and clear cache

Comment: Run di:compile in your root Magento directory it should work